# iPhone sdk UITableView cell reuse identifier

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am using UITableView. When a book is downloaded i am adding a checkmark image to my table. And i have done this. But when am scrolling my table am getting the image even for non-downloaded books (i.e) my table cell are reused. For this i googled and checked my code with that. Everything seems to be the same. Here is my code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

      UIImage *cellImage= [cacheImage getCachedImage:[listOfThumImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      if(cellImage == nil)
{
    DeviantDownload *download;
    download = [DownloadsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cellImage = download.image;
    if (cellImage == nil)
    {
        download.delegate = self;
    }

NSLog(@"cellImage%@",cellImage);
UIImageView *imgView;


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"";

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

} 

  imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(680, 60, 40, 40)];//self.view.bounds.size.width-
    [imgView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Downloaded.png"]];

  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([defaults objectForKey:@"firstRun"])
    {
       if([[[appDelegate selectDB] valueForKey:@"bookname"] containsObject:[listOfBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] )
      {
           NSString *cellValue = [listOfBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           cell.contentView addSubview:imgView1];
      }
   return cell;

    }
 }

}
```

What's wrong with my code? Kindly help me out. Thanking You.

Comment: You are reusing a cell with an image. Therefore the image is still there because you haven't told your view controller that the image should not be there when the cell is reused.

Comment: Since i need the image only after downloading, i added there. So how come i can avoid re-using my image? in this criteria?

Comment: The easies way is to create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and make the download image view a property of that class. Then in cellForRow you set the image to the Downloaded.png to show it or to nil to hide it.

Comment: can u please explain me in detail with sample code? am new to this platform.

Comment: No, sorry. You have to ask the search engine of your choice for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that a cell does not display the image then simply remove the imageview, for that cell. set a view.tag for the image view, and retrieve it, then remove it.

What you are doing now, is to add a image sub view as soon as you need it for a cell, and later reuse that cell for all other rows. But you never removed the imageview for cells that dont need it.

Comment: can you please explain me in detail?

Comment: what you didnt understand?

Comment: I am able to understand, but will get clear if you explain me with sample code or in detail.

Answer (score 0):

CheckMarks with `UITableView` is little complicated then what it seems. First of all you'll have to save the status of your row which already has the bookmark. And, compare it in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. What you can do is create on `NSMutableArray`. Save 1 for downloaded book and 0 for non-downloaded book. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method compare [array objectAtIndex:indexpath.row] and set the image accordingly.

Also, change :

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"";
```

To :

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
```